# Remove redundant parameters from equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, replacement, fitting

I have random expressions like

```
(b1 x + b2 x)/(b3 + b4/b5 x) + Sin[b6 x]
```

where $x$ is a variable and {b1, ..., b6} are parameters to be fitted. This expression is obviously over-parametrized.

I am looking for a general method to remove the redundant parameters and obtain a simpler parametrization. For this particular example, the method should return

```
(c1 x)/(c2 + c3 x) + Sin[c4 x]
```

where {c1, ..., c4} are new parameters.

Comment: Yes. My goal is to give Mathematica an expression containing b's and x, and that it returns a new expression containing c's and x which has a simpler parametrization (ideally non-redundant).

Comment: Does it have to work only for this expression? It's quite "easy" to do, but it's very case dependant. See [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TXnbr.png).

Comment: Ideally, it should work for any expression. Indeed, the solution for a given expression (as the one in the question) is obvious. It is not obvious how to write an algorithm that solves the problem in a more general situation.

Comment: If I correctly understand, you don't want refit the data  according to new nonlinear model.

Comment: what is the problem with fitting your first expression ? fitting will make any unnecessary parameters equal 0.

Comment: @user1879 Yes. The idea is to use the new model (with better parametrization) to fit data. Not necessarily, using the FindFit Mathematica function.

Comment: @Algohi The problem lies in that the size of number of b's grows much faster than the c's as the size of the expression grows. Hence, the time needed to correctly fit the parameters is also larger.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to come close. The idea is to find factors, at all levels, that are not numeric and are independent of the variable. Set up replacement rules for these in terms of some new symbol. Do the replacement. I also return the rules used in case that might be useful.

```
replaceFactors[expr_, x_, c_Symbol] := Module[
  {e2 = MapAll[Collect[#, x] &, ee], fax, rule, revrule},
  fax = Cases[e2, 
    aa_*bb_.*x /; ! NumericQ[aa] && 
       FreeQ[aa, x] && (NumericQ[bb] || ! FreeQ[bb, x]) :> aa, 
    Infinity];
  rule = Thread[fax -> Array[c, Length[fax]]];
  {rule, e2 /. rule}
  ]
```

This may need some further work, for example maybe the `/.` at the end should instead be `//.`. Anyway here is the example in question.

```
ee = (b1 x + b2 x)/(b3 + b4/b5 x) + Sin[b6 x];
replaceFactors[ee, x, c]

(* Out[40]= {{b4/b5 -> c[1], b1 + b2 -> c[2], b6 -> c[3]}, (x c[2])/(
  b3 + x c[1]) + Sin[x c[3]]} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more try:

```
relations = 
 SolveAlways[(b1 x + b2 x)/(b3 + (b4/b5) x) == (c1 x)/(c2 + 
       c3 x), {x}][[4]]
```

> {b3 -> ((b1 + b2) c2)/c1, b4 -> ((b1 + b2) b5 c3)/c1}

This gives nontrivial relations between parameters you should always keep for any x. Convert them to equations and remove some freedom

```
restrictions = Equal @@@ relations;

myChoice = {b1 == c1};
```

At last

```
Solve[Flatten[{restrictions, myChoice}], {c1, c2, c3}]
```

Now you solved for unknown coefficients. Is it your goal?
In particulary if you will try

```
myChoice = {b3 == c2}
```

you will obtain obvious solution.

Comment: No. The point is that the correct parametrization (using parameters c's) is unknown. I am looking for an algorithm to obtain it.

Comment: The problem is that you are using the correct parametrization (using the c's) to produce your answer. The goal is to precisely obtain such parametrization.

Comment: Well, but then your c_i parametrization is still overparametrized (your can divide numerator and denominator by c2 and remove one constant more).

Comment: That is indeed correct.

Comment: As far as as understand, the question then is of general character. Seems, that You simply should count independent terms. These are {1,x, x^2,...}, so you take c1+c2 x+c3 x^2. If you need rational function, then simply take (c1+c2 x+c3 x^2)/(1+d1 x+d2 x^2). In this case, however, polynomials in nominator and denominator cannot have common roots and in general there is no general way (I think)  to ensure these when fitting data. As far as concerns more general functions the question seems to me mathematically undecidable, i.e. it is equivalent for testing if two expressions are equal.